# Inverse of a roto-translation matrix in 3D space

Tags: matrices, inverse, 3d, rotations, transformation

I want to create two roto-translation matrices. The first transforms point $P$ into point $P'$ by performing a translation $T=(x_t, y_t, z_t)$ and two rotations (one around the $x$ axis of $\alpha$ and the second around the $y$ axis of $\beta$). The second undoes the previous transformation by transforming the point $P'$ into $P$. The first transformation works correctly and I calculated it as follows:

$$\pmatrix{P'\\1}=
\pmatrix{P\\1}
\pmatrix{
cos(\alpha) & sin(\beta)sin(\alpha) & cos(\beta)sin(\alpha) & x_t\\
0 & cos(\beta) & -sin(\beta) & y_t\\
-sin(\alpha) & sin(\beta)cos(\alpha) & cos(\beta)cos(\alpha) & z_t\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
}=
\pmatrix{
P_x*cos(\alpha) + P_y*sin(\beta)sin(\alpha) + P_z*cos(\beta)sin(\alpha) + x_t\\
P_x*0 + P_y * cos(\beta) - P_z*sin(\beta) + y_t\\
-P_x*sin(\alpha) + P_y*sin(\beta)cos(\alpha) + P_z*cos(\beta)cos(\alpha) + z_t\\
1
}
$$

I have calculated the second transformation as follows but it does not seem to be correct if $x_t$, $y_t$ and $z_t$ is greater than zero:

$$\pmatrix{P\\1}=
\pmatrix{P'\\1}
\pmatrix{
cos(\alpha) & 0 & -sin(\alpha) & -x_t\\
sin(\beta)sin(\alpha) & cos(\beta) & sin(\beta)cos(\alpha) & -y_t\\
cos(\beta)sin(\alpha) & -sin(\beta) & cos(\beta)cos(\alpha) & -z_t\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
}=
\pmatrix{
P'_x*cos(\alpha) + P'_y*0 - P'_z*sin(\alpha) - x_t\\
P'_x*sin(\beta)sin(\alpha) + P'_y * cos(\beta) - P'_z*sin(\beta)cos(\alpha) - y_t\\
P'_x*cos(\beta)sin(\alpha) - P'_y*sin(\beta) + P'_z*cos(\beta)cos(\alpha) - z_t\\
1
}
$$

Do you see any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{T}$ be the translation matrix, and $\mathbf{R}$ the rotation matrix: $$\mathbf{T} = \left[\begin{matrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & T_x \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & T_y \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & T_z \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right], \quad \mathbf{R} = \left[ \begin{matrix}
\cos\alpha & \sin\beta \sin\alpha & \cos\beta \sin\alpha & 0 \\
0 & \cos\beta & -\sin\beta & 0 \\
-\sin\alpha & \sin\beta \cos\alpha & \cos\beta \cos\alpha & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]$$
Because rotations are combined by multiplying the matrices with the applied transform on the left (i.e., oldest rightmost, newest leftmost), the combined transformation matrix $\mathbf{M}_{T,R}$ if the translation is done *first* and rotation *second* is
$$\mathbf{M}_{T,R} = \mathbf{R} \mathbf{T} = \left[\begin{matrix}
\cos\alpha & \sin\beta \sin\alpha & \cos\beta \sin\alpha & T_x \cos\alpha + T_y \sin\beta \sin\alpha + T_z \cos\beta \sin\alpha \\
0 & \cos\beta & -\sin\beta & T_y \cos\beta - T_z \sin\beta \\
-\sin\alpha & \sin\beta \cos\alpha & \cos\beta \cos\alpha & -T_x \sin\alpha + T_y \sin\beta \cos\alpha + T_z \cos\beta \cos\alpha \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]$$
On the other hand, if the rotation is done first and translation second, the transformation matrix is $\mathbf{M}_{R,T}$,
$$\mathbf{M}_{R,T} = \mathbf{T} \mathbf{R} = \left[\begin{matrix}
\cos\alpha & \sin\beta \sin\alpha & \cos\beta \sin\alpha & T_x \\
0 & \cos\beta & -\sin\beta & T_y \\
-\sin\alpha & \sin\beta \cos\alpha & \cos\beta \cos\alpha & T_z \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]$$
Any combination (product) of pure rotation and pure translation matrices is invertible.  The key thing to note is that inverting the result is the same as inverting each matrix, *and the order*; see e.g. the Wikipedia article on [matrix inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_inverse#Other_properties).  That is,
$$\mathbf{M}_{T,R}^{-1} = \left( \mathbf{R} \mathbf{T} \right)^{-1} = \mathbf{T}^{-1} \mathbf{R}^{-1}$$
and
$$\mathbf{M}_{R,T}^{-1} = \left( \mathbf{T} \mathbf{R} \right)^{-1} = \mathbf{R}^{-1} \mathbf{T}^{-1}$$
Pure rotation matrices are orthonormal, and their inverse is their transpose,
$$\mathbf{R}^{-1} = \mathbf{R}^{T} = \left[\begin{matrix}
\cos\alpha & 0 & -\sin\alpha & 0 \\
\sin\beta \sin\alpha & \cos\beta & \sin\beta \cos\alpha & 0 \\
\cos\beta \sin\alpha & -\sin\beta & \cos\beta \cos\alpha & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]$$
see e.g. Wikipedia [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) article.  For translation matrices, you negate the translation vector (rightmost column, except for the fourth element in the lower right corner of the matrix), i.e.
$$\mathbf{T}^{-1} = \left [ \begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & -T_x \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -T_y \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -T_z \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right ]$$
You can verify this by [inverting $\mathbf{T}$ by hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Inversion_of_4_%C3%97_4_matrices).

Combining all of the above, we see that
$$\mathbf{M}_{T,R}^{-1} = \left( \mathbf{R} \mathbf{T} \right)^{-1} = \mathbf{T}^{-1} \mathbf{R}^{-1} = \left[\begin{matrix}
\cos\alpha & 0 & -\sin\alpha & -T_x \\
\sin\beta \sin\alpha & \cos\beta & \sin\beta \cos\alpha & -T_y \\
\cos\beta \sin\alpha & -\sin\beta & \cos\beta \cos\alpha & -T_z \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]$$
and
$$\mathbf{M}_{R,T}^{-1} = \left( \mathbf{T} \mathbf{R} \right)^{-1} = \mathbf{R}^{-1} \mathbf{T}^{-1} = \left[\begin{matrix}
\cos\alpha & 0 & -\sin\alpha & -T_x \cos\alpha + T_z \sin\alpha \\
\sin\beta \sin\alpha & \cos\beta & \sin\beta \cos\alpha & -T_x \sin\beta \sin\alpha - T_y \cos\beta - T_z \sin\beta \cos\alpha \\
\cos\beta \sin\alpha & -\sin\beta & \cos\beta \cos\alpha & -T_x \cos\beta \sin\alpha + T_y \sin\beta - T_z \cos\beta \cos\alpha \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]$$

Thus, we can easily see the error in OP's inversion: they forgot to also invert the order of the matrices in the product.